# How to use .svg in iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, web-applications, svg

I am creating iPad application for showing shops in shopping mall as arial view, the application landed with normal size image. When do pinching or zoom in, to expand and show row wise shops, more zooming, it need to show shop wise and click on the shop and show information about the shop and what shop is this. How should i use svg format in this application and how to get the coordinates clicked area. Please help me out to done app? or give any other solution like whether the app may be native or web?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using PaintCode ([www.paintcodeapp.com](http://www.paintcodeapp.com)) for that. It can import SVG files and generates resolution-independent Objective-C drawing code on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

For the SVG, use a UIWebView... see this [article](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/)

For the touch events you can use a Javascript framework such as jQueryTouch in coordination with the SVG.

As an alternative, check out RaphaelJS... really nice and works perfectly with iOS.